# Android wifi control

Tags: android, wifi

I want to make an android app that prevents user to use directly WIFI, in other word, the android app demands from user to enter a password when turning on WiFi on android phone or tablet.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WifiManager` to toggle it and set a `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED` to know when it is manually switched and then prompt for a password.

Comment: After using BroadcastReceiver i can turn wifi off automatically from app and display the password screen, if user enter a correct password the app re turn on the wifi?

Comment: Yes, that would be my suggestion.

Comment: Note that you should implement your own methods to process the events of the turning on and off of the wifi as well as the actions to do so. `BroadcastReceiver` is just a class used to receive system broadcast events and nothing more.